# Bash pass argument to --init-file script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I'm running a shell script using `bash --init-file script.sh` that runs some commands, then leaves an interactive session open. How can I pass arguments to this init file from the process that runs the initial bash command? `bash --init-file 'script.sh arg'` doesn't work.

Interestingly, if the script contains `echo "$# $*"`, passing an argument as I did above causes it to print nothing, while not passing an argument prints '0'.

Comment: I'd like the arg to come from the command that runs bash with the --init-file. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
script.sh arg
```

Pass that file to bash: `bash --init-file thatfile`

> I'd like the arg to come from the command that runs bash with the

Create a file from the command line and pass it:

```
arg="$1"
cat >thatfile <<EOF
$(declare -p arg)
script.sh \"\$arg\"
EOF
bash --init-file thatfile
```

You might be interested in researching what is a *process substitution* in bash.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think of using a temporary file. I know what process substitution is, but I thought that wouldn't work since this script is for running a container

Comment: For those taking this approach, take special care to note whether your $VARIABLE expansions are happening when the file is created vs when it runs.